# Terraform: Why AWS NAT Gateway conflicts with Egress Only Internet Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have both IPv4 and IPv6, I'm trying to manage a Routing for private subnet.

Once NAT Gateway is attached to Route Table, it does not allow me to attach Egress Gateway to the same route table, and giving me an error:

> **An interface that is part of a NAT gateway cannot be the next hop for an IPv6 destination CIDR block or IPv6 prefix list**

However if I'm attaching manually thought AWS Console, there is no problem

[image: Manual Attachment worked as expected]

Maybe I'm missing some info? I know that NAT only for IPv4 and Egress only for IPv6, can someone guide me on this? Why if NAT not compatible with Egress Only Gateway, it allows me to attach via **aws console**, but not with terraform?

Here is my simple terraform

```
resource "aws_eip" "neip"  {
   count = length(var.private_subnet) 
   vpc   = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
   count = length(var.private_subnet) 
   subnet_id     = element(var.public_subnet, count.index)
   allocation_id = element(aws_eip.neip.*.id, count.index)
}
resource "aws_egress_only_internet_gateway"  "egw"  {
   count  = length(var.zones) > 0 ? 1 : 0
   vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}
resource "aws_route_table" "route" {
   count = length(var.private_subnet) 
   vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_route" "ipv4" {
   count           = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   depends_on      = [ aws_route_table.route ]
   route_table_id  = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
   nat_gateway_id  = element(aws_nat_gateway.nat.*.id, count.index)
   destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_route" "ipv6"  {
   count                   = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   depends_on              = [ aws_route_table.route ]
   route_table_id          = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
   egress_only_gateway_id  = element(aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.egw.*.id, count.index)
   destination_ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route" {
   count          = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   subnet_id      = var.private_subnet[count.index]
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
}
```

No issue with terraform script

[image]

Comment: Can you provide actuall example TF code which can demonstrate the issue and allow for its reproduction?

Comment: Hello, @Marcin, I've added the terraform file

Comment: Interesting. Theoretically this should not be a problem. An issue with Terraform, maybe?

Comment: Can you check the sequence of API calls in AWS CloudTrail to e see which specific action fails?

Comment: Does this code even work? Because you are using `count` to define `aws_nat_gateway`, but then you are referencing it using regular `aws_nat_gateway.nat.id`? Can you provide what are these `var.private_subnet` and the rest of variables?

Comment: @Marcin, as you may see in screenshot, everything is creating except the action where route table association. Regarding variables `var.private_subnet` and `var.public_subnet` is already created and it is list of strings with 3 elements. I fixed the typo with `nat`

Comment: So it seems the code you provided here is not the one you are using. If `var.private_subnet` has three elements, then you will  have 3 NAT gateways, resulting in syntax error at `aws_nat_gateway.nat.id`.

Comment: @Marcin, the code I'm using is what I've provided, I was trying some other stuffs, and accidentally made a mistake, but I've fixed the typo

Comment: @DennisTraub, unfortunately in that region the cloud trail was disabled by SSO admin

Comment: I see. From a security perspective that can prove very problematic, though. CloudTrail should always be active for every region and not logging your API calls is strongly advised against. Having that said, CloudTrail automatically stores the events of the last 90 days, even if no tail is active. Can you have a look at those? They can be found in the CloudTrail console under “Events”.

Comment: @DennisTraub, I've looked almost everywhere in CloudTrail events, nothing were written, last activity were in 5th of January, and it is related to ASG only

Comment: Nothing? Not even the events related to you trying it manually as depicted above? Then I would assume that you’re looking either in the wrong region or the wrong account.

Comment: @DennisTraub, I'm working on Ireland region, and when I was looking the events, I've searched in every region, by switching them, there is a manual actions from other team members, but no action from my user who is actually executes `terraform apply`

Comment: I think it is related to AWS, I was trying to do same thing with AWS CLI, and it gave me the same error, and as I said with AWS Console, no errors and gives me what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **tried to reproduce** your issue, but for me it works as expected. Maybe you still have some "typos" in your code presented here, thus its difficult to see why it woudn't work for you.

Anyway, here is the code I used in order to mimic your setup, though large chunks I had to create myself, as they are not shown in your code (e.g. VPC setup all missing, internet gateway, public subnets).

The code below works and I couldn't replicate your issue. **Route tables work as expected**:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = true
    tags = {
        Name = "testvpc"
    }
}

variable "private_cidrs" {
    default = ["10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
}

variable "public_cidrs" {
    default = ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {

    count = length(var.public_cidrs)

    cidr_block = var.public_cidrs[count.index]
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
    tags = {
        Name = "public${count.index}"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {

    count = length(var.private_cidrs)

    cidr_block = var.private_cidrs[count.index]
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
    tags = {
        Name = "private${count.index}"
    }
}

resource "aws_eip" "neip"  {
   count = length(var.private_cidrs) 
   vpc   = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
   count         = length(var.private_cidrs) 
   subnet_id     = element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, count.index)
   allocation_id = element(aws_eip.neip.*.id, count.index)
   
   depends_on    = [aws_internet_gateway.igw]
}

resource "aws_egress_only_internet_gateway"  "egw"  {
   #count  = length(var.private_cidrs) 
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

# routes for public subnets

resource "aws_route_table" "public_route" {
   count = length(var.public_cidrs) 
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route" "public_ipv4" {
   count           = length(aws_route_table.public_route) 
   route_table_id  = aws_route_table.public_route[count.index].id
   gateway_id  = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
   destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_route" "ipv6_public"  {
   count                   = length(aws_route_table.public_route) 
   route_table_id          = aws_route_table.public_route[count.index].id
   egress_only_gateway_id  = aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.egw.id
   destination_ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_route" {
   count          = length(aws_route_table.public_route) 
   subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet[count.index].id
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route[count.index].id
}

# routes for private subnets

resource "aws_route_table" "route" {
   count = length(var.private_cidrs) 
   vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route" "ipv4" {
   count           = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   route_table_id  = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
   nat_gateway_id  = aws_nat_gateway.nat[count.index].id
   #nat_gateway_id  = aws_nat_gateway.nat.id
   destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_route" "ipv6"  {
   count                   = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   route_table_id          = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
   egress_only_gateway_id  = aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.egw.id
   destination_ipv6_cidr_block = "::/0"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route" {
   count          = length(aws_route_table.route) 
   subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_subnet[count.index].id
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.route[count.index].id
}
```